# Add Service ref to Windows Service within current solution?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, service-reference

I have a solution that contains 2 projects, 1 client(consol) and 1 windows service(debugs in console). The problem is that the client needs a service ref to the service but its not possible to add a service ref while running. It is also not possible to find the service while not running even when using the Discover button?

I supose I could start another Visual Studio with the same project and just start the service but is there really no better way to solve this?

BestRegards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 (or higher) you should be able to find a service in the current solution via the "Discover" button. Please try to rebuild and follow the instractions in the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Okay, the problem is, that it is Widnows Service (sorry I was sure I read WCF service). The Windows Service is not working using the "Discover" button. You can try to add a reference via the "Reference Manager" (right click on the "References" item in the project tree) and add a reference from the "Solution".